# Return only certain values of my JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

Apologies in-advance for the long post.So currently, my JSON is coming out as seen below, and I only want to return the `name` value of the items in Filter 1, with the corresponding `category` `name`. What is the best way for me to do so?

I assume this is a backend fix, so I have also included my backend below. Any help would be appreciated, as I often don't work with JSON.

```
{
   "urls":{
      “Url1”:{
         "status":200
      }
   },
   “Filter1”:[
      {
         "slug”:”slug1,
         "name”:”name1”,
         "confidence":100,
         "version":null,
         "icon”:”icon1”,
         "website”:”website1”,
         "cpe":"cpe1”,
         "categories":[
            {
               "id":22,
               "slug”:”slug2”,
               "name”:”name3”
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "slug”:”slug3”,
         "name”:”name4”,
         "confidence":100,
         "version":null,
         "icon”:”icon2”,
         "website”:”website2”,
         "cpe":null,
         "categories":[
            {
               "id":30,
               "slug”:”slug4”,
               "name”:”name5”
            },
            {
               "id":75,
               "slug”:”slug5”,
               "name”:”name6”
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Backend:

```
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  res.render('index',{
      data: 'name'
  })
})

app.post('/', async(req, res) => {

  const whoissearch = new whoissearch()

  try {
      await whoissearch()

      const url = req.body

      let urlEncoded = decodeURIComponent(url.url);

      await whoissearch.init();
      const site = await whoissearch.open(urlEncoded)
      site.on('error', console.error) // catch the errors
      const results = await site.analyze()


      const data = JSON.stringify(results, null, 2)
      console.log(results.whois[0].name)

      await whoissearch.destroy()

      res.render('index', {
          data: data
      });
```

Sample of how it is being shown:
[image]

Comment: What does `data` look like?

Comment: @StackSlave Currently, when it is rendered, it comes out not formatted into proper JSON. Just all across three lines.

Comment: If that was what you are referring to

Comment: Show us a mock-up.

Comment: @StackSlave updated

Comment: @StackSlave some peices are missing, but it is just meant to give you an idea of how it is being shown

Comment: Learn how to read JSON.